# Dealing with multi-language directories (Python)

Tags: python, unicode, decode

I'm trying to open a file and I just realized that py is having trouble with my username (It's in Russian). Any suggestions on how to properly decode/encode this to make idle happy?

I'm using py 2.6.5

```
xmlfile = open(u"D:\\Users\\Эрик\\Downloads\\temp.xml", "r")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    xmlfile = open(str(u"D:\\Users\\Эрик\\Downloads\\temp.xml"), "r")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

os.sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'mbcs'

xmlfile = open(u"D:\Users\Эрик\Downloads\temp.xml".encode("mbcs"), "r")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    xmlfile = open(u"D:\Users\Эрик\Downloads\temp.xml".encode("mbcs"), "r")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'D:\Users\Y?ee\Downloads\temp.xml'

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the parser tries to interpret backslashes in strings unless you use the `r"raw quote"` prefix. In 2.6.5, you needn't treat your Unicode string specially, but you may need a file encoding declaration in your source code like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

as defined in [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/). Here is an example of it working interactively:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
>>> f = r"D:\Users\Эрик\Downloads\temp.xml"
>>> f
'D:\\Users\\\xd0\xad\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\\Downloads\\temp.xml'
>>> x = open(f, 'w')
>>> x.close()
>>> 
$ ls D*
D:\Users\Эрик\Downloads\temp.xml
```

Yes, this is on a Unix system so the `\` isn't meaningful and my terminal encoding is utf-8, but it works. You just may have to give the coding hint to the parser when it is reading a file.

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

```
xmlfile = open(u"D:\\Users\\Эрик\\Downloads\\temp.xml", "r")
### The above line should be OK, provided that you have the correct coding line
### For example # coding: cp1251

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    xmlfile = open(str(u"D:\\Users\\Эрик\\Downloads\\temp.xml"), "r")
### HOWEVER the above traceback line shows you actually using str()
### which is DIRECTLY causing the error because it is attempting
### to decode your filename using the default ASCII codec -- DON'T DO THAT.
### Please copy/paste; don't type from memory.
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Second problem:**

`os.sys.getfilesystemencoding()` produces `'mbcs'`

```
xmlfile = open(u"D:\Users\Эрик\Downloads\temp.xml".encode("mbcs"), "r")
### (a) \t is interpreted as a TAB character, hence the file name is invalid.
### (b) encoding with mbcs seems not to be useful; it messes up your name ("Y?ee").

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in xmlfile = open(u"D:\Users\Эрик\Downloads\temp.xml".encode("mbcs"), "r")
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'D:\Users\Y?ee\Downloads\temp.xml'
```

**General advice on hard-coding filenames in Windows**, in descending order of preference:

(1) Don't
(2) Use `/` e.g. `"c:/temp.xml"`
(3) Use raw strings with backslashes `r"c:\temp.xml"`
(4) Use doubled backslashes `"c:\\temp.xml"`